# Building Kaldi on a Mac running macOS Catalina

Tags: intel-mkl, kaldi

I’m using a Mac Pro running macOS Catalina (v10.15.1).  Has anyone managed to build Kaldi with this version of the OS?

Specifically,  one of Kaldi's dependencies is the Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL or some other suitable matrix algebra library).  MKL does not have a version that is compatible with Catalina.  I’m open to using another library, but I’d need some guidance on how to install another library and make it run with Kaldi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaldi can use the [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate) framework as a replacement for OpenBLAS/MKL. Its by far the easiest way to build Kaldi on osx and ios.

Comment: Could you, please, provide some example how kaldi could be configured with this framework?

Answer (score 1):

Try [OpenBlas](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS)

Install it as usual - `./configure && make && make install`

Then Kaldi with openblas - `./configure --mathlib=OpenBLAS`